# How to change from 10 to 100 (items per page) in publisher and devportal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

This is second question today.

Does anyone know how to change the apis view number below from 10 to 100 by default?
(API Manager 4.0 using)

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not configurable out of the box. In case of developer portal, you may need to do customization for ApiTableView.jsx or use option of changing it from the "Items per page" drop-down itself.

Comment: noted..Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

There is no config to change this value. You will need to do the customization in the source code files. For the publisher portal, you need to update the `TableView.jsx` file. To do this you need to copy the specific file to `publisher/override/src` directory, update it with changes and finally build the react app.

Step 1: Copy the `TableView.jsx` to `<API-M_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/override/src/app/components/Apis/Listing/TableView` directory(you will be manually create the directory path to match the source file location)

Step 2: Make the necessary changes

Step 3: Build the react app.

- Navigate to `<API-M_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps` and run the following commands to install the npm packages and bootstrap,

  `npm install`

  `npm run bootstrap`
- Once the above is completed run the following command `npm run build:prod` from the `devportal` directory.

Please refer the official documentation [Advanced UI Customization](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/reference/customize-product/customizations/advanced-ui-customization/) for more information.